# Quickly escape special characters while building a string

Tags: c#, regex, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a `JSON` string to send to my `MVC` view for a `jQuery UI autocomplete`.  I do it manually because it allows me to take any `DataTable`, specify the value and id columns using any column in the table.

I build the string like this:

```
public static string CreateJsArray(DataTable dt, string idCol, string valCol)
{    
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    DataView sortedDv = dt.DefaultView;
    sortedDv.Sort = valCol;

    dt = sortedDv.ToTable();

    sb.Append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
     sb.AppendFormat(
        i > 0
           ? ", {2} \"value\":\"{0}\", \"label\": \"{0}\", \"id\": \"{1}\" {3}"
           : "{2} \"value\":\"{0}\", \"label\": \"{0}\", \"id\": \"{1}\" {3}",
        dt.Rows[i][valCol].ToString().Trim().Replace("\"", "\\\""), 
        dt.Rows[i][idCol].ToString().Trim().Replace("\"", "\\\""), 
        "{", 
        "}");
     }
     sb.Append("]");

     return string.Format("{0} \"items\": {1}{2}", "{", sb, "}");
}
```

I need to escape all the characters I expect my users to have in the fields, but don't really want to add a `.Replace()` for all options.  Is there a faster way to do it?

#### Answer

Although I didn't use the answer selected, it did put me on the path that worked well.  This is the approach that I took:

```
public static string CreateItemJSON(DataTable dt, string idCol, string valCol)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jRow = Enumerable.Select(dt.AsEnumerable(), row => new ItemRows { 
                   id = row.Field<string>(idCol), 
                   label = row.Field<string>(valCol).TrimEnd() 
               }).ToList();
    var jTable = new Item { items = jRow };
    return serializer.Serialize(jTable);
}
public class ItemRows
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public List<ItemRows> items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use a ViewModel or create anonymous type and return to the client :)

for eg :

```
public JsonResult getAutoCompletedata(string query)
{
    var query = from p in dt.AsEnumerable() //dt is the datatable
                        where p.Field<string>("code") == query
                        select new
                        {
                            value = p.Field<string>("yourColumnName"),
                            lable= p.Field<string>("YourAnotherColumnName")                         
                        }.ToList();
    return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I like the approach, but can't get it to work (I haven't really used Linq).  I updated the question to show that I am passing the dt, idCol and valCol.  Also, I don't want to filter the records in the dt.  With that, how would I make your code work?  Thanks for your help.